# Can login attempt 6 times in salesforce before user unlock even thought it is set to 5?

Tags: login, developer, setup, login-errors, passwords

I have set the maximum valid attempt to 5 before user get unlock in 'password policies' in Setup while the lockout effective period is forever, however even after 6 attempts of invalid password, user is still not locked. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the user has different password policies set on the Profile level.

As per Salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_password_policies.htm&type=5),

> To ensure that the appropriate level of password security is used for
> your organization, specify password requirements with Password
> Policies settings for users assigned to a profile. Profile Password
> Policies settings override the organization-wide Password Policies for
> that profile’s users. If you do not set Password Policies on a
> profile, the organization-wide Password Policies apply. New profile
> Password Policies take effect for existing profile users when they
> reset their passwords.

Comment: Hi, I was using the System Administrator account. Already check that everything is correct under profile settings. But unfortunately, still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm curious if this is simply because you were using a user with the System Admin profile. Have you tried testing the lockout policy on a user with a non System Admin profile?